# Embed javascript code in a django template

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

Based on this Highcharts example (javascript code included in a HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/f4Ef7/

I have a template where I want to embed that JavaScript code without having to include any static. Anything not related with JS is being processed by the browser. Currently my **views.py** looks like:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from tfgplot.models import estado_foneras
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('tfgplot/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render(request, 'tfgplot/index.html', context)
```

My application is called tfgplot and the template **index.html** looks like:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 1em">
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
{% autoescape off %}
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
{% endautoescape %}
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

This should create a graphic like the one that can be seen in the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Ef7/) but I'm not able to see that graphic I'm expecting, any ideas?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If this is all the thing you have in the template then there are several things... Your container div should be in the body I think. And you should import the jquery too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your html is quite messy, here are a few things:

1. Every `div` or almost any other html tag should reside inside the `body` tag.
2. You should load the scripts inside the `head` tag or at the end of the `body` tag.
3. You should wait until the DOM is ready to create the chart or do any other javascript work.
4. You need `jQuery` in order to make `$('#container')` work.
5. `div` elements as `container` must be closed.
6. You shouldn't add `css` styles to a html element directly. Instead do it in a separate file (something like `styles.css`).
7. There's no need for your `script` to be inside a `div`, you could get rid of it.

Here is a code that should do what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 1em">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {% autoescape off %}
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#container').highcharts({
              xAxis: {
                  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
              },
              series: [{
                  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
              }]
          });
      });
      {% endautoescape %}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more information about html/css standards check [this link](http://google%C2%ADstyleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml) from google.

Also, since you are working with django, you need to be aware of template inheritance. If the above code doesn't work, share more code and/or errors information.